# SQL: Creating updatable view duplicating values from table

Tags: sql, oracle

On oracle 12g i've got a table

```
CREATE TABLE OLDTABLE ("COLOR" CHAR(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, "OBJECT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE);
create or replace synonym SYN_TO_OLDTABLE for OLDTABLE;
```

with a list of colors/object, say "BLK", "CUP"

```
INSERT INTO OLDTABLE(COLOR,OBJECT_TYPE) values ('BLK','CUP');
COMMIT;
```

I have a need to not add rows inside OLDTABLE and to duplicate values such that all "BLACK" items are also "GREEN", so i created a view

```
create or replace view VW_TO_OLDTABLE as 
   select COLOR, OBJECT_TYPE from OLDTABLE
  UNION
   select 'GRN', OBJECT_TYPE from OLDTABLE where COLOR = 'BLK'
   ;
```

Now i'm happy, and i replace the synonym to show the view instead of the table.

```
create or replace synonym SYN_TO_OLDTABLE for VW_TO_OLDTABLE;
```

Now i'm very happy with the rusult, but i've got one problem... the problem is that i need the view to be updatable, but oracle documentation says that it cannot be done, since the view has an UNION statement.

```
   insert into SYN_TO_OLDTABLE(COLOR,OBJECT_TYPE)  values ('AAA','BBB');
   commit;
```

Documentation and online research also suggest to use instead of triggers, it would be ok, but i have to repeat the same procedure for many other tables (like 150), with many more columns and i don't want to create 350 triggers since it would be hell to maintain (add/remove columns, alter table, alter columns and so on).

So... the question is:

- is there another way to duplicate values without using the UNION statement and without adding rows to the table?

Thanks

Comment: Is your Oracle instance set up with partitioning?

Comment: Yes, i use it for other tables

Comment: Not much related, but if your table *doesn't contains* the green color, you may use `UNOIN ALL` instead of `UNION` (view remains non updatable, but will be more performant). If you have *green now* you have other problems. You should also add the *expectations of the updates*. What do you expect if you updates *green to black*?

Comment: That's a good question: I need that insert, update and delete insist only on the BLK item

Comment: i've got another input... i have a different table with colors list